# How can I test an Electron application using Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, electron, selenium-chromedriver

We have Electron version 23.1.1 and corresponding chromium version is 110.0.5481.104.
Link for this: `https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/tag/v23.1.1`
I downloaded chromedriver-v23.1.1-win32-x64.zip from the above page.

> I started a small test but the only step I get is opening the application and than this message in console "Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: no such window: target window already closed".

I am open to use anything but I don't want to ditch java for JavaScript?
This is my code.

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Set;

public class LoginTest {

    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginTest.class);
    private WebDriver driver = null;
    private ChromeOptions options;
    private WebElement inputPOSUser;
    private WebElement clickNextButton;
    @Before
    public void Setup(){
        options = new ChromeOptions();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\CustomChromeDriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging", "true");
        options.setBinary("C:\\PATH\\TO\\ELECTRONAPP.exe");
        options.addArguments("start-maximized"); 
        options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222"); //9222
        if (driver == null){
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10) );

            //for printing browser name and version
            Capabilities cp = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities();
            System.out.println("Browser: " + cp.getBrowserName());
            System.out.println("Version: " + cp.getBrowserVersion());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
//                switchToNewWindow(driver);
                inputPOSUser=  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("login-username-input")));
                driver.findElement(By.id("login-login-button"));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

        }


    }

    @Test
    public void TestL(){

        LOGGER.info("Step");
        String User = "newuser";
        driver.get("http://localhost:4202/login");
        inputPOSUser.sendKeys(User);
        LOGGER.info("entered login name");
        clickNextButton.click();
    }


    @After
    public void teardown() {
        if (driver != null)
            driver.quit();
    }

    public  void switchToNewWindow(WebDriver driver)
    {
        String mainWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
        Set<String> openedWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();
        if(openedWindows.size() > 1)
        {
            for(String newWindow : openedWindows)
            {
                driver.switchTo().window(newWindow);
            }
            driver.close();
            LOGGER.info("Closing the current Opened Window - Invoice");
            driver.switchTo().window(mainWindow);
        }
    }

}
```

This is the console

```
"
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (LoginTest).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Starting ChromeDriver 110.0.5481.104 (46de4a7f41979e829b430bc1ee30ef483aa227ac-refs/branch-heads/5481_77@{#19}) on port 7863
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[1687340263.626][INFO]: [34022d8904f2f63ebd53781d89c6b5a3] COMMAND InitSession {
   "capabilities": {
      "firstMatch": [ {
         "browserName": "chrome",
         "goog:chromeOptions": {
            "args": [ "start-maximized", "enable-automation", "--no-sandbox", "--remote-debugging-port=9222" ],
            "binary": "C:\\AFC\\PointOfSale\\PointOfSale.exe",
            "extensions": [  ]
         }
      } ]
   },
   "desiredCapabilities": {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "goog:chromeOptions": {
         "args": [ "start-maximized", "enable-automation", "--no-sandbox", "--remote-debugging-port=9222" ],
         "binary": "C:\\AFC\\PointOfSale\\PointOfSale.exe",
         "extensions": [  ]
      }
   }
}
[1687340263.629][INFO]: Populating Preferences file: {
   "alternate_error_pages": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "autofill": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "browser": {
      "check_default_browser": false
   },
   "distribution": {
      "import_bookmarks": false,
      "import_history": false,
      "import_search_engine": false,
      "make_chrome_default_for_user": false,
      "skip_first_run_ui": true
   },
   "dns_prefetching": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "profile": {
      "content_settings": {
         "pattern_pairs": {
            "https://*,*": {
               "media-stream": {
                  "audio": "Default",
                  "video": "Default"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "default_content_setting_values": {
         "geolocation": 1
      },
      "default_content_settings": {
         "geolocation": 1,
         "mouselock": 1,
         "notifications": 1,
         "popups": 1,
         "ppapi-broker": 1
      },
      "password_manager_enabled": false
   },
   "safebrowsing": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "search": {
      "suggest_enabled": false
   },
   "translate": {
      "enabled": false
   }
}
[1687340263.633][INFO]: Populating Local State file: {
   "background_mode": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "ssl": {
      "rev_checking": {
         "enabled": false
      }
   }
}
[1687340263.637][INFO]: Launching chrome: "C:\AFC\PointOfSale\PointOfSale.exe" --allow-pre-commit-input --disable-background-networking --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --enable-automation --enable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0 --enable-logging --log-level=0 --no-first-run --no-sandbox --no-service-autorun --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=9222 --start-maximized --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir="C:\Users\UserProfile\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir117580_1083242216" data:,
[1687340263.651][DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Request: http://localhost:9222/json/version
[1687340264.226][DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Response: {
   "Browser": "Chrome/110.0.5481.104",
   "Protocol-Version": "1.3",
   "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) PointOfSale/1.0.0 Chrome/110.0.5481.104 Electron/23.1.1 Safari/537.36",
   "V8-Version": "11.0.226.16",
   "WebKit-Version": "537.36 (@46de4a7f41979e829b430bc1ee30ef483aa227ac)",
   "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://localhost:9222/devtools/browser/bd8c11d3-9ff1-4a4c-9ce9-fdb9619d0210"
}

[1687340264.226][DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Request: http://localhost:9222/json/list
[1687340264.228][DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Response: [ {
   "description": "",
   "devtoolsFrontendUrl": "/devtools/inspector.html?ws=localhost:9222/devtools/page/3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66",
   "id": "3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66",
   "title": "",
   "type": "page",
   "url": "file:///C:/AFC/PointOfSale/resources/app.asar/html/start.html",
   "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://localhost:9222/devtools/page/3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66"
} ]

[1687340264.255][INFO]: resolved localhost to ["::1","127.0.0.1"]
[1687340264.257][WARNING]: virtual void DevToolsClientImpl::AddListener(DevToolsEventListener *) subscribing a listener to the already connected DevToolsClient. Connection notification will not arrive.
[1687340264.258][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Target.getTargets (id=1) (session_id=) browser {
}
[1687340264.259][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Target.getTargets (id=1) (session_id=) browser {
   "targetInfos": [ {
      "attached": false,
      "browserContextId": "9EEB1F223152D98321FD4F4558501009",
      "canAccessOpener": false,
      "targetId": "3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66",
      "title": "",
      "type": "page",
      "url": "file:///C:/AFC/PointOfSale/resources/app.asar/html/start.html"
   } ]
}
[1687340264.259][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Target.attachToTarget (id=2) (session_id=) browser {
   "flatten": true,
   "targetId": "3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66"
}
[1687340264.260][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: Target.attachedToTarget (session_id=) browser {
   "sessionId": "C5798C306B0019F541FAFF88D3DDC14B",
   "targetInfo": {
      "attached": true,
      "browserContextId": "9EEB1F223152D98321FD4F4558501009",
      "canAccessOpener": false,
      "targetId": "3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66",
      "title": "",
      "type": "page",
      "url": "file:///C:/AFC/PointOfSale/resources/app.asar/html/start.html"
   },
   "waitingForDebugger": false
}
[1687340264.260][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Target.attachToTarget (id=2) (session_id=) browser {
   "sessionId": "C5798C306B0019F541FAFF88D3DDC14B"
}
[1687340264.260][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument (id=3) (session_id=C5798C306B0019F541FAFF88D3DDC14B) 3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66 {
   "source": "(function () {window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Array = window.Array;window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Promise = window.Promise;window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Symbol = window.Symbol;}) ();"
}
[1687340264.260][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Runtime.evaluate (id=4) (session_id=C5798C306B0019F541FAFF88D3DDC14B) 3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66 {
   "expression": "(function () {window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Array = window.Array;window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Promise = window.Promise;window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Symbol = window.Symbol;}) ();"
}
[1687340264.261][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Log.enable (id=5) (session_id=C5798C306B0019F541FAFF88D3DDC14B) 3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66 {
}
[1687340264.261][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Target.setAutoAttach (id=6) (session_id=C5798C306B0019F541FAFF88D3DDC14B) 3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66 {
   "autoAttach": true,
   "flatten": true,
   "waitForDebuggerOnStart": false
}
[1687340264.261][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Page.enable (id=7) (session_id=C5798C306B0019F541FAFF88D3DDC14B) 3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66 {
}
[1687340264.262][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Page.enable (id=8) (session_id=C5798C306B0019F541FAFF88D3DDC14B) 3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66 {
}
[1687340264.294][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument (id=3) (session_id=C5798C306B0019F541FAFF88D3DDC14B) 3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66 {
   "identifier": "1"
}
[1687340264.294][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Runtime.evaluate (id=4) (session_id=C5798C306B0019F541FAFF88D3DDC14B) 3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66 {
   "result": {
      "type": "undefined"
   }
}
[1687340264.294][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Log.enable (id=5) (session_id=C5798C306B0019F541FAFF88D3DDC14B) 3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66 {
}
[1687340264.294][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Target.setAutoAttach (id=6) (session_id=C5798C306B0019F541FAFF88D3DDC14B) 3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66 {
}
[1687340264.294][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Page.enable (id=7) (session_id=C5798C306B0019F541FAFF88D3DDC14B) 3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66 {
}
[1687340264.294][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Page.enable (id=8) (session_id=C5798C306B0019F541FAFF88D3DDC14B) 3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66 {
}
[1687340264.294][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Runtime.enable (id=9) (session_id=C5798C306B0019F541FAFF88D3DDC14B) 3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66 {
}
[1687340264.295][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: Page.domContentEventFired (session_id=C5798C306B0019F541FAFF88D3DDC14B) 3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66 {
   "timestamp": 1207352.837148
}
[1687340264.298][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: Runtime.executionContextCreated (session_id=C5798C306B0019F541FAFF88D3DDC14B) 3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66 {
   "context": {
      "auxData": {
         "frameId": "3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66",
         "isDefault": false,
         "type": "isolated"
      },
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Electron Isolated Context",
      "origin": "file://",
      "uniqueId": "-4165743087318469963.1924850320221961557"
   }
}
[1687340264.298][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: Runtime.executionContextCreated (session_id=C5798C306B0019F541FAFF88D3DDC14B) 3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66 {
   "context": {
      "auxData": {
         "frameId": "3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66",
         "isDefault": true,
         "type": "default"
      },
      "id": 1,
      "name": "",
      "origin": "file://",
      "uniqueId": "-966553648842666591.1831066268359020716"
   }
}
[1687340264.298][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Runtime.enable (id=9) (session_id=C5798C306B0019F541FAFF88D3DDC14B) 3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66 {
}
[1687340264.298][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Page.enable (id=10) (session_id=C5798C306B0019F541FAFF88D3DDC14B) 3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66 {
}
[1687340264.300][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Page.enable (id=10) (session_id=C5798C306B0019F541FAFF88D3DDC14B) 3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66 {
}
[1687340264.300][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Runtime.enable (id=11) (session_id=C5798C306B0019F541FAFF88D3DDC14B) 3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66 {
}
[1687340264.310][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: Page.loadEventFired (session_id=C5798C306B0019F541FAFF88D3DDC14B) 3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66 {
   "timestamp": 1207352.842856
}
[1687340264.310][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Runtime.evaluate (id=12) (session_id=C5798C306B0019F541FAFF88D3DDC14B) 3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66 {
   "awaitPromise": false,
   "expression": "document.readyState",
   "returnByValue": true
}
[1687340264.310][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: Page.frameStoppedLoading (session_id=C5798C306B0019F541FAFF88D3DDC14B) 3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66 {
   "frameId": "3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66"
}
[1687340264.310][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Runtime.enable (id=11) (session_id=C5798C306B0019F541FAFF88D3DDC14B) 3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66 {
}
[1687340264.311][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Runtime.evaluate (id=12) (session_id=C5798C306B0019F541FAFF88D3DDC14B) 3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66 {
   "result": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "complete"
   }
}
[1687340264.312][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Runtime.evaluate (id=13) (session_id=C5798C306B0019F541FAFF88D3DDC14B) 3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66 {
   "awaitPromise": true,
   "expression": "(function() { // Copyright 2012 The Chromium Authors\n// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be\n// found in the LICENSE file.\n\n/**\n * Enum for WebDriver status codes....",
   "returnByValue": true
}
[1687340264.315][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Runtime.evaluate (id=13) (session_id=C5798C306B0019F541FAFF88D3DDC14B) 3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66 {
   "result": {
      "type": "object",
      "value": {
         "status": 0,
         "value": 1
      }
   }
}
[1687340264.315][INFO]: [34022d8904f2f63ebd53781d89c6b5a3] RESPONSE InitSession {
   "capabilities": {
      "acceptInsecureCerts": false,
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "browserVersion": "110.0.5481.104",
      "chrome": {
         "chromedriverVersion": "110.0.5481.104 (46de4a7f41979e829b430bc1ee30ef483aa227ac-refs/branch-heads/5481_77@{#19})",
         "userDataDir": "C:\\Users\\UserProfile\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\scoped_dir117580_1083242216"
      },
      "goog:chromeOptions": {
         "debuggerAddress": "localhost:9222"
      },
      "networkConnectionEnabled": false,
      "pageLoadStrategy": "normal",
      "platformName": "windows",
      "proxy": {
      },
      "setWindowRect": true,
      "strictFileInteractability": false,
      "timeouts": {
         "implicit": 0,
         "pageLoad": 300000,
         "script": 30000
      },
      "unhandledPromptBehavior": "dismiss and notify",
      "webauthn:extension:credBlob": true,
      "webauthn:extension:largeBlob": true,
      "webauthn:virtualAuthenticators": true
   },
   "sessionId": "34022d8904f2f63ebd53781d89c6b5a3"
}
[1687340265.977][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: Target.detachedFromTarget (session_id=) browser {
   "sessionId": "C5798C306B0019F541FAFF88D3DDC14B",
   "targetId": "3D5D926A00E7B99A43C30D657DB31A66"
}
[1687340274.428][INFO]: [34022d8904f2f63ebd53781d89c6b5a3] COMMAND GetWindow {
}
[1687340274.453][INFO]: [34022d8904f2f63ebd53781d89c6b5a3] RESPONSE GetWindow ERROR no such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found
  (Session info: chrome=110.0.5481.104)
[1687340274.462][INFO]: [34022d8904f2f63ebd53781d89c6b5a3] COMMAND Quit {
}
[1687340274.515][INFO]: [34022d8904f2f63ebd53781d89c6b5a3] RESPONSE Quit
[1687340274.515][DEBUG]: Log type 'driver' lost 1 entries on destruction
[1687340274.515][DEBUG]: Log type 'browser' lost 0 entries on destruction

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: no such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found
  (Session info: chrome=110.0.5481.104)
Build info: version: '4.8.1', revision: '8ebccac989'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '19.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [34022d8904f2f63ebd53781d89c6b5a3, getCurrentWindowHandle {}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 110.0.5481.104, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 110.0.5481.104 (46de4a7f419..., userDataDir: C:\Users\UserProfile\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:9222}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:9222/devtool..., se:cdpVersion: 110.0.5481.104, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 34022d8904f2f63ebd53781d89c6b5a3
```

Comment: You know that Electron is Javascript, right? I don't understand why you would choose to do it like that.

Comment: We want to do like that because in our team we do not have js developers/testers. They devs are with java, front end is developed in other team and testers stick with java/C#. And now you tell me what should i doo? Fire all?

Comment: @pguardiario you didn't add any value to this question.

Comment: You would have to make electron launch with --remote-debugger somehow and then google for how to connect to a running window.